# Al ejecutar composer install el proyecto de laravel crece mas de 2gb

Tags: php, laravel, composer

tengo un problema al clonar un proyecto de laravel. He creado un proyecto de laravel e inmediatamente lo he subido tal como esta a github, luego desde otra maquina lo he clonado y he ejecutado "composer install", ademas de que demora un monton en descargar el proyecto termina pesando mas de 2gb, cuando al inicio al crearlo tan solo pesaba 64mb, porque pasa esto?

Como ya mencione, intente hacer el proceso con un proyecto laravel de cero, es decir, sin modificar nada del codigo, simplemente como estaba, pero el problema es al ejecutar "composer install", termina el proyecto pesando mas de 2gb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontre la respuesta, lo que pasa es que estaba ejecutando "composer install" en el proyecto desde vs code pero aparecia mensajes como este: Failed to download mockery/mockery from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping. Al parecer es porque no habia una extesion zip para descomprimirlos, entonces al no poder descomprimirlos buscaba en github la dependencia y la descargaba desde ahi, por eso tenia archivos .git en cada carpeta de las dependecias entre otros archivos extra.
La solucion era ejecutar composer install desde la git bash, ya que ahi si puede extraer archivos zip

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.